# WP7: Accessing image data of WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've got a  `WebBrowser` on my phone UI (from Microsoft.Phone.Controls), showing web page with images. How do I access the html image binary data?

I want to store the image for later rendering, and perhaps do some image transformations for it too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that since WebBrowser control is pretty much sandboxed and you don't have access to DOM or anything inside it.

EDIT: You can at least get the HTML source for the page and you could then parse the source, extract urls for images and then manually download them. You can get the source via the [WebBrowser.SaveToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.savetostring%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) method

Comment: I am sure it fares better. Anyway, I have updated my answer with additional info. Maybe you can manually retrieve images. It is still not an answer to your original question, but it serves as a workaround.